# Нужна помощь со скрытием Status Bar

Tags: android, activity

Мне нужно скрыть `Status Bar` на андроиде, в том смысле что бы он вообще не появлялся, я сделал так что бы он скрывался, но при нажатии на экран он все равно вылазить и скрыть его программно можно только через 10 секунд после нажатия, не знаю что это за хитрость и как ее обойти. Когда пытался как-то переопределять метод `onTouch` все равно не работает, нашел только один выход из ситуации поставить на метод `setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener` скрытие самого статус бара таймером через 10 секунд.

```
 public  void timer1(){
    CountDownTimer time_activity = new CountDownTimer(10000, 100) {
        public  void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility( View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
        }
        public void onFinish() {
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility( View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);

        }
    }.start ();
}
```

Нужно сделать что бы он вообще не появлялся, как это можно сделать? Использую `Surface` для воспроизведения видео, может это как-то влияет на появления `Satus Bar`?

Comment: вот такой костыль: CountDownTimer time_activity = new CountDownTimer(1, 1)

Comment: @adamluissean это как бы не работает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно прописать в теме:

```
<application
...
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >
...
</application>
```

а можно программно:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // If the Android version is lower than Jellybean, use this call to hide
    // the status bar.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
...
```

и так:

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
 // Hide the status bar.
  int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
  decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
  // Remember that you should never show the action bar if the
  // status bar is hidden, so hide that too if necessary.
  ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
  actionBar.hide();
```